# Magento 1.9 Where is the translation file defined?

Tags: magento-1.9, localisation

In my Magento folder, under locale/ I have a list of folders with translation files, and I have configured different Magento stores in Admin.

[image]

But some stores don't use the correct translation file. Where Can I set the correct file for each Magento store? Does this need to be done in code or in Admin?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The locale can be defined per store via Magento Admin

This is in System -> Configuration -> General, then goto the 'locale' tab.

The locale defined here corresponds to the folders in your screenshot, e.g en_US for English (US).

```
af_ZA = Afrikaans (South Africa)
sq_AL = Albanian (Albania)
ar_DZ = Arabic (Algeria)
ar_EG = Arabic (Egypt)
ar_KW = Arabic (Kuwait)
ar_MA = Arabic (Morocco)
ar_SA = Arabic (Saudi Arabia)
az_AZ = Azerbaijani (Azerbaijan)
be_BY = Belarusian (Belarus)
bn_BD = Bengali (Bangladesh)
bs_BA = Bosnian (Bosnia and Herzegovina)
bg_BG = Bulgarian (Bulgaria)
ca_ES = Catalan (Spain)
zh_CN = Chinese (China)
zh_HK = Chinese (Hong Kong SAR China)
zh_TW = Chinese (Taiwan)
hr_HR = Croatian (Croatia)
cs_CZ = Czech (Czech Republic)
da_DK = Danish (Denmark)
nl_NL = Dutch (Netherlands)
en_AU = English (Australia)
en_CA = English (Canada)
en_IE = English (Ireland)
en_NZ = English (New Zealand)
en_GB = English (United Kingdom)
en_US = English (United States)
et_EE = Estonian (Estonia)
fil_PH = Filipino (Philippines)
fi_FI = Finnish (Finland)
fr_CA = French (Canada)
fr_FR = French (France)
gl_ES = Galician (Spain)
ka_GE = Georgian (Georgia)
de_AT = German (Austria)
de_DE = German (Germany)
de_CH = German (Switzerland)
el_GR = Greek (Greece)
gu_IN = Gujarati (India)
he_IL = Hebrew (Israel)
hi_IN = Hindi (India)
hu_HU = Hungarian (Hungary)
is_IS = Icelandic (Iceland)
id_ID = Indonesian (Indonesia)
it_IT = Italian (Italy)
it_CH = Italian (Switzerland)
ja_JP = Japanese (Japan)
km_KH = Khmer (Cambodia)
ko_KR = Korean (South Korea)
lo_LA = Lao (Laos)
lv_LV = Latvian (Latvia)
lt_LT = Lithuanian (Lithuania)
mk_MK = Macedonian (Macedonia)
ms_MY = Malay (Malaysia)
mn_MN = Mongolian (Mongolia)
nb_NO = Norwegian Bokmål (Norway)
nn_NO = Norwegian Nynorsk (Norway)
fa_IR = Persian (Iran)
pl_PL = Polish (Poland)
pt_BR = Portuguese (Brazil)
pt_PT = Portuguese (Portugal)
ro_RO = Romanian (Romania)
ru_RU = Russian (Russia)
sr_RS = Serbian (Serbia)
sk_SK = Slovak (Slovakia)
sl_SI = Slovenian (Slovenia)
es_AR = Spanish (Argentina)
es_CL = Spanish (Chile)
es_CO = Spanish (Colombia)
es_CR = Spanish (Costa Rica)
es_MX = Spanish (Mexico)
es_PA = Spanish (Panama)
es_PE = Spanish (Peru)
es_ES = Spanish (Spain)
es_VE = Spanish (Venezuela)
sw_KE = Swahili (Kenya)
sv_SE = Swedish (Sweden)
th_TH = Thai (Thailand)
tr_TR = Turkish (Turkey)
uk_UA = Ukrainian (Ukraine)
vi_VN = Vietnamese (Vietnam)
cy_GB = Welsh (United Kingdom)
```

Comment: Thanks, does the folder has to be a certain name e.g. en_US in order Magento can find out it is for English (US)?

Comment: Added list of locales for you